# How to purchase the right transformer for an electronic device

Tags: voltage, transformer, dc

I just purchased an IP telephone that comes with no power transformer.  I think the manufacturer assumes that buyers will be using power over ethernet.

On the back of the phone where the power jack is it says DC, 24V-30V.  Under an input section it says: +24V 235mA, -48V 130mA.  I purchased the unit in the UK.

It is an NEC IP phone.

I am confused with the input +27V and -48V?  Is that a range because it is AC?

Would a device labelled as  "Universal UK mains power supply 9V-12V AC/DC 1A PSU charger" be suitable?  What should I be looking for?

I am thinking this item might be suitable:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B006FHJAX0/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I believe the owner's manual should be clear.

PROVIDING POWER

IP telephones require power to function. This can be provided in various ways:

5.1 Local Power

The IP telephone and IP-R Unit have a connector for external power. This is supplied by a AC adapter that outputs 27V DC. This means that a main socket is required in the vicinity of each IP Phone, and loss of mains power in the building will prevent the phones from working. **You should only use the power supply supplied by NEC.**

5.2 Powered Patch Panel

A powered patch panel has two RJ-45 connectors per IP Phone. One port connects to the switch/hub, and the other port connects to the IP Phone. The patch panel has an integral power supply that adds power to the spare pins of the RJ-45.

When the IP Phone is connected to the powered patch panel, it automatically receives its power via the spare pairs on the Cat-5 cable - there is no need for a local power adapter.

5.3 Power Over Ethernet (PoE)

A PoE switch is a switched hub that also provides power over the spare pairs. The switch can be used with any device (not just IP phones) and will detect if power is required or not. As all of the phones receive their power from one device, it is easy to protect the IP phones from loss of power (by connecting the PoE switch to a UPS).

Comment: Maybe show a picture and provide a link to the unit  but the question might get closed down because it's not really about electronic/electrical design/engineering it's about some product that probably nobody else has.

Comment: simplest way would be to use POE injector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the label by hte power jack says "DC, 24 - 30V", and other documentation says +24V 235 mA, I would say that you need a 24 - 30 Volt DC power supply, capable of supplying 250 mA or more.

The "Universal UK mains supply" you mention is definitely not suitable.

-48 volts is a common telephone system voltage. I don't know how that relates to your phone - perhaps POE?'

Answer (score 0):

I believe the device you want is called a "PoE injector".

They cost around $20-$40 and you can then do away with the wall wart supply at the IP phone and just have a single supply (and a single Ethernet cable) for the phone.

Comment: Yes I realise PoE is best way to go but I am doing some in-house testing on a single IP phone so just want a cheap power adapter.